# Is there an index or cheat-list of the various endpoints available?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, routes, endpoint

I know I can infer many names like `/user` or `/me` by looking at the data types or reading the documentation.  But I was wondering if there's a place where a list of all the various endpoints and possible routes are maintained?

Comment: `/post` isn't an endpoint afaik

Comment: Amended, although that might have just proven my point! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended place to look for this would be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/examples/ anywhere else and you are always going to be a step or more behind.

Though, on a first jab at it, there is on the first level

```
/me
/app
/{user-id}
/{page-id}
/{app-id}
/{user-username}
/{page-username}
/{object-id}
/{url}

/oauth

/fql

/search
```

Comment: Just one more I would like to list out `/debug_token`